# Number theory in Mathematica

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, cryptography

Is there any book out there similar to S. Wagon's *Mathematica in Action* that has problems/exercises/projects in the field of number theory as done in Mathematica? If not pure number theory, at least something for cryptography?

Comment: "Computational Recreations in Mathematica" by Ilan Vardi, long out of print but available used, may be of number theoretic interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[A course in computational number theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930190107)*** by David Bressoud and Stan Wagon (Wiley, 2000)